# PHP Classes - How to call them properly

Tags: php, class

Here's what I'm pretty sure I can do, just don't know how to do it.

```php
class My_Looping_Class {

   public function __construct() {
        $this->vars = new My_Vars_Class();  //maybe this goes here???
        for($y=0;$y<=10;$y++) {
             $this->do_loop();
        }
   }

   private function do_loop() {
    //in this loop the value of $x in My_Var_Class gets incremented each loop but I'm not exactly 
    //sure how to call it.  Something like this????
    $this->vars->x++;
   }
}

class My_Var_Class {

  public $x = 0;

}

class My_Looping_Class_Copy extends My_Looping_Class {
     // Here I need to be able to read and echo the value of x in My_Var_Class each time it 
     //changes but again, I'm unsure of how to call it.
}

new My_Looping_Class_Copy();
```

Tried to post this with just the code above and it complained I didn't have enough details. So, here goes:

What I'm attempting to do is to write a web crawler similar to PHPCrawl. In PHPCrawl you basically set the parameters for the crawler (crawl depth, follow redirects, timeout, etc.), set the url, call a "go" function in the main class and it starts crawling pages. As it crawls each page it updates another class that contains all of the result variables, like response time, links found, etc. After it finishes each page crawl, through a class extension, you're able to access all of those variables and process them as you please. After that, it crawls another url it found and updates the result variables.

I tried reading through the code but got lost pretty quick as to how the author did this. The code above is just a very basic example of how PHPCrawl works.

Here's a link to the PHPCrawl example code: http://phpcrawl.cuab.de/example.html What I'm trying to duplicate is the handleDocumentInfo($DocInfo) function.

Comment: I believe your wording might be a bit of. You _call_ a method of a class, you _access_ property of a class and you _instantiate_ a class.

Comment: In your case, if you want to access `&x`, you could use: `$newClass = new My_Looping_Class_Copy(); 
echo $newClass->x;`

Comment: Yea, the terminology always confuses me.  Sorry.  So I don't understand.  How does $newClass->x read the My_Var_Class x?

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake `$newClass = new My_Var_Class()` will create an instance of your class that hass the property `x`.

Comment: Right, I know I need to create one and it needs to be in My_Looping_Class somewhere.  What I still don't understand is how to  read each change in the $x in My_Var_Class from the My_Looping_Class_Copy.

Comment: You got _one_ downvote (and it probably wasn't anyone here who was trying to help you), and no close votes. Patience, no need to stress. There are clear reasons why downvotes may be given abs "elitism" isn't one of them. So, yeah maybe your question is a little tricky, it's hard to see what you're trying to achieve, it could be a little tighter and less verbose. But one downvote in an hour...actually it's probably an ok question, keep going. the _actually_ bad ones usually last about 30 seconds before they get 10 downvotes, 3 close votes and a deletion flag.

Comment: You have 3 classes in your code, with the my_looping_class_copy having access to the  my_looping_class  's public and protected members, there is nothing linking the my_var_class to anything, it is its own class, if you want to have access to the member of my_var_class, you have to make it either a member or a derived class.

Comment: Right, that's what I need to understand how to do.  How to link the vars to the loop so that every time the loop increments x, the copy can see that value change and, for example, echo it.  When this code is run, the $x should get incremented and My_Looping_Class_Copy should output 1,2,3,4, etc.

Comment: And I tried to be less verbose and SO said I wasn't verbose enough and wanted more text.

Comment: I understand it is frustrating people downvote your question, but realize people are  primarily here to help you. Downvotes usually occur when the question is unclear, lacking code, or without a reproducable problem. In your case, it probably has to to with it being unclear.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, here's an example of how you can get the value of a property of one class and use it in another one. Extending that other one, instantiating it, and getting the new value of the property:

```
class My_Looping_Class {
    
    public $xCopy;

    public function __construct() {
        $varClass = new My_Var_Class();
        $this->xCopy = $varClass->x + 10; // Here i add 10 to this class propert 'xCopy'. Loop or do whatever you want with it instead.  
   }
}

class My_Var_Class {

  public $x = 33; // Just some number as an example. 
}

class My_Looping_Class_Copy extends My_Looping_Class {
   
}

$loopClassCopy = new My_Looping_Class_Copy();

echo $loopClassCopy->xCopy; // Should output 43 (33 + 10)
```

Or see this [working example](https://3v4l.org/6FNG7).

Comment: Not exactly.  You removed the for-loop.  The purpose of that was to simulate the crawler indexing web pages.  With your example of $x=33 and the for loop back in the looping class I'd expect the output to be 33, 34, 35, 36... 43.

Comment: `$xCopy` is a single property (with a single value) of your class. If you want multiple values either make it into an array or have multiple instances of your class. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for trying. I guess I'm just unable to explain this well enough.

Comment: If it crawls 10000 web pages, stores the html, links and other data in an array before processing it, that array would be huge. That's why the output of x is needed each time it loops so that it can be either unset or reset to a default number.

Comment: Ok, got something to work but it's not pretty:
https://3v4l.org/Qlsca
And my logic was off on the output for my purposes. This is what it should look like since the $x would need to be reset back to 0 every iteration of the loop so, it'll always = 1.

Comment: I am sorry, but I still do not really understand what you are trying to do. Well, crawling some pages I guess, but there are so many ways this can be done and it really depends on what you want to do with the crawled information. With regards to your original question, it is too broad really. Try to create function that do one thing only (regardless of what class they are in) and then see what issue you run into. Also realize that this structure you are using is, well, just some way to handle this. There surely are other options that might make more sense.